# Ruby DBI: How to add the execute arguments when use method "in (?)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dbi

Here is my sample code for using DBI:

```
begin
  dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:Test:localhost", "testuser", "testpassword")

  sql = "select u.email, u.account_name, u.height, u.weight 
         from test_users 
         where id in (?)
         group by u.id
         order by u.id
         into outfile '/tmp/test.csv'
         fields terminated by ','
         enclosed by '\"'
         lines terminated by '\n'"

  sth = dbh.prepare(sql)
  sth.execute('1,2,3')
  sth.finish
rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
  puts "An error occurred"
  puts "Error code:    #{e.err}"
  puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
ensure
  # disconnect from server
  dbh.disconnect if dbh
end
```

But the sql it gives me like, the value of "in" method is incorrect:

```
  select u.email, u.account_name, u.height, u.weight 
  from test_users 
  where id in ('1,2,3')
  group by u.id
  order by u.id
  into outfile '/tmp/test.csv'
  fields terminated by ','
  enclosed by '\"'
  lines terminated by '\n'"
```

I want to like this(notice the change result is: "id in (1,2,3)"):

```
   select u.email, u.account_name, u.height, u.weight 
   from test_users 
   where id in (1,2,3)
   group by u.id
   order by u.id
   into outfile '/tmp/test.csv'
   fields terminated by ','
   enclosed by '\"'
```

Comment: have you tried it in an array `([1,2,3])`

Comment: @PraveshKhatri I'm tried it, and it gives me like this: '[1,2,3]'

Comment: I'm just looking the sql, and without looking the result. Actually the previous code also is right. although the sql looks unfriendly, but the select results is right. And thank you for your answers, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how the IN clause works, you need to have the same amount of `?` as the number of arguments, in your case, you should have:

```
sql = "select u.email, u.account_name, u.height, u.weight 
         from test_users 
         where id in (?,?,?)
         group by u.id
         order by u.id
         into outfile '/tmp/test.csv'
         fields terminated by ','
         enclosed by '\"'
         lines terminated by '\n'"
```

and then pass each value to the query.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, you can generate the placeholders using `map` and `join`:

```
foo = 'foo'
bar_array = [1, 2, 3]
bar_placeholders = bar_array.map { '?' }.join(', ')
baz = 18
sql = <<-SQL
  SELECT * FROM t
  WHERE foo = ?
  AND bar IN (#{bar_placeholders})
  AND baz > ?
SQL
...
sth.execute(foo, *bar_array, baz)
```

This will automatically generate the appropriate number of question marks, and quote the parameters correctly.